# Change Points in Cox Model

Tags: time-series, survival, cox-model, change-point

I have trained a Cox model on my dataset, which comprises patients entering the study at various time points. I suspect there might be multiple change points indicating shifting effects over time. My goal is to test for the presence of these change-points and to identify them.

Could anyone recommend R packages or methodologies that are suitable for this task? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help ?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15279/change-point-in-cox-survival-model